# Unexpected Output from Array() Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this snippet of code below and don't quite understand the output

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  if (num <0) {
    return ""
  } else {
  return Array(num+1).join(str)
  }
}

console.log(repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3));
```

I would have expected the output to be "abcabcabc" though if I console.log(repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3)) in JS Bin it produces "abcabc"?

If I specify Array(3) - Would it not concatenate the string 3 times? Why only 2 in this instance?

Comment: The output is `abcabcabc` (so abc 3x times) - which is expected, because your passing in `3`

Answer (score 5):

> If I specify Array(3) - Would it not concatenate the string 3 times?
> Why only 2 in this instance?

```js
console.log([1,2,3].join('abc'))
// outputs 1abc2abc3
```

Note that `'abc'` is the separator for the join between the 3 elements, and so it appears twice, not 3 times.

Therefore, if you create an empty array, it shows `'abc'` twice, separating 3 empty strings:

```js
console.log(Array(3).join('abc'))
// outputs abcabc
```

Also note that there is `String.repeat()`

```js
console.log('abc'.repeat(3))
// outputs abcabcabc
```

Answer (score 1):

look when i run your code the right output appears so your code has no bugs, and when you specify Array(3) the output will be "abcabc" your code is working well

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy

Answer (score 0):

If you will have a look into the [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) documentation, It will join the array items based on the passed separator in the join method. Ideally, It will not consider the join before the first and after the last element in an array.

```js
console.log(Array(3)) // [undefined, undefined, undefined]

console.log([undefined, undefined, undefined].join('abc')); // 'abcabc'
```

As you want to fill the array with the string, Correct method is [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) which changes all elements in an array to a static value, from a start index (default `0`) to an end index (default `array.length`) and then join the elements from an array with the help of `Array.join()` method.

```js
console.log(Array(3).fill('abc').join(''));
```